# Creating a simple model

Tags: gazebo-model, mesh

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi. I am trying to create a simple cylindrical shape model for Gazebo. To do so, I just copy and edit the existing cylindrical.model in /simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.0.2/models to the dimensions I want. However, the model dissappear the moment i inserted them in Gazebo.

This is my model file

```
    <gazebo version="1.0">
    <model name="cylinder">
      <link name="link">
        <origin pose="0 0 0.5 0 0 0"/>
        <inertial mass="1.0">
          <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>

        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.127" length="1.245"/>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.127" length="1.245"/>
          </geometry>
          <material script="Gazebo/Green"/>
       </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
    </gazebo>
```

After some reading up, it seems that my mistake is I did not create a mesh file for the new model I created. Is my guess correct?

If so, another question will be where should I place the mesh file at? The original cylinder.model did not seems to have a mesh file.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/557/creating-a-simple-model/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-11**:
the cylinder as it is defined in your sdf intersects with the ground plane with 0.1225m of overlap.  This translates to an impulse of erp * 0.1225m / dt to be applied to the model upwards.  Given the position of link is 0.5m from the ground plane, changing cylinder length to 1.0m should help.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2013-01-19**:
Thank you. i will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The version of Gazebo that you are referencing in deprecated. I'll post and answer for Gazebo 1.3.

1. Start gazebo: `gazebo`
2. Insert a Cylinder using the toolbar located about the render window
3. Save the World using `File->Save World As`
4. Open the saved world using your favorite editor.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2013-01-19**:
Thanks nkoenig. I guess i should upgrade my version of gazebo.